# How to save multiple videos into application document directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, nsdocumentdirectory, phasset

I am using GMImagePicker to fetch assets of camera roll.
After selecting single or multiple videos i got PHAsset in arrayArray.
assetArray data in this formate

```
 "<PHAsset: 0x7fe0e8f21130> 40D4733D-4C7B-443D-8093-C28E39ACA45E/L0/001 mediaType=2/0, sourceType=1, (720x480), creationDate=2016-02-14 09:50:58 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0 "
```

How can i store this video into my application document directory?
The code i did to store video is

```
for (PHAsset *asset in assetArray) {

        if (asset.mediaType==PHAssetMediaTypeVideo) {
            NSLog(@"Video found");
        }
        PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
        options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;

        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {

            if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
                NSURL *URL = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL];

               NSMutableData *responseData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
               responseData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
                if (responseData.length>0) {
                        NSString * lastPath = [URL.absoluteString lastPathComponent];//videoname.mp4
                        NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES)objectAtIndex:0];
                        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDirPath,lastPath];

                       [responseData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            }
        }];

       }
```

I also checked filepath where video is saved. Video is available but i get this error.

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to me use NSMutableData instead of NSData it's accept Nullable value

```
self.responseData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
if (self.responseData.length>0) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString * lastPath = [url.absoluteString lastPathComponent];//videoname.mp4
        NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES)objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDirPath,lastPath];
            [self.responseData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
    });
```

hope this help you.

Comment: Please provide your complete error log. OR check your url on any browser. It's downloading the data or not?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: i checked URL in safari. its completely run video

Comment: At last line   [self.responseData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

Comment: NSURL *URL = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL];
Please check this URL object. It has same url of your video or not?

Comment: Yes it is the same video i selected, i checked URL in safari.

Answer (score 0):

For storing both Images And Video

```
 for (PHAsset *asset in assetArray) {

        if (asset.mediaType==PHAssetMediaTypeVideo) {
            NSLog(@"Video found");

            PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
            options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;

            [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {

                if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
                    NSURL *URL = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL];
                   [Albumvideos addObject:URL];
                    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
                    if (videoData.length>0) {
                        NSString *lastPath = [URL.absoluteString lastPathComponent];
                        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",TimeStamp,lastPath]];
                        [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:videoData attributes:nil];   
                    }
                }
            }]; 
        }
else{

    self.requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    self.requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
    self.requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;

    // this one is key
    self.requestOptions.synchronous = true;

    //  self.assets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:assets];
    PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];

    // assets contains PHAsset objects.
    __block UIImage *ima;


        // Do something with the asset

        [manager requestImageForAsset:asset
                           targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                          contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                              options:self.requestOptions
                        resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
                            ima = image;

                            [Albumimages addObject:ima];

                        }];

}
}
```

Albumvideos is mutable array which contain video URL and Albumimages contain selected images.